# PHP displaying several results

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I have 2 results displaying in  my database. Both results are representing cars. I need to display these results in the form created below. Currently it displays one result successfully but i need to display several results from these tables. I will be adding more cars once i get it working. Any ideas?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
            <title>
            </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
            </script>
            <script src="my.js">
            </script>
            <!-- User-generated css -->
            <style>
            </style>
            <!-- User-generated js -->
            <script>

                try {

        $(function() {

        });

      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
      }
            </script>
         </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Home -->
            <div data-role="page" id="page1">
                <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                        Back
                    </a>
                    <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                     Home  
                    </a>
                    <h3>
                        Book Car
                    </h3>
               </div>

               <div data-role="content">
                    <h3>
                        Select the car to rent from the availability:
                    </h3>
                    <br />
            <?php

            {
                mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
                mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


                $pid=intval($_SESSION["User_id"]); 
                $query = "SELECT `car`, `details`, `price` FROM `Car`";

                //executes query on the database
                $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

                //this selects the results as rows
                $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    


                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {

                    $_SESSION['car'] = $row['car'];
                    $_SESSION['details'] = $row['details'];
                    $_SESSION['price'] = $row['price'];
                }
            }
            ?>  
    <html>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="car.php">
     Car: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['car']; ?>" readonly><br>
     Details: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['details']; ?>" readonly><br>
     Price: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?>" readonly><br>
     <img style="width: 130px; height: 100px" img alt="car"src="image/astra.jpg" /&gt;' />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

       Car: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['car']; ?>" readonly><br>
     Details: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['details']; ?>" readonly><br>
     Price: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?>" readonly><br>
     <img style="width: 130px; height: 100px" img alt="car"src="image/audi.jpg" /&gt;' />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">


    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This requires a complete rebuild of your logic. Although you are looping the returned result fine but you are overwriting your values with every run of the loop and after the loop your `SESSION` variables will contain data from only the last row, which you display in HTML below. So that displayed html also has to be a part of your loop if you have to show all the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output the form within the loop, as at the moment your just over riding the session variables so you'll get the last car in the table.

```
<form method="post" action="car.php">

<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

  Car: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['car']; ?>" readonly><br>
  Details: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['details']; ?>" readonly><br>
  Price: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" readonly><br>
  <img style="width: 130px; height: 100px" img alt="car"src="image/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" /&gt;' />

<?php } ?>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'd suggest storing the image name in the database as well as shown above. At the moment that form is pretty redundant to be honest though as when you submit it you will just submit the last car in the form, you need to work out a way of allowing the user to select the car they want.

EDIT: Code to select a specific car

I just put this together real quick, sorry for any mistakes.

```
<form method="post" action="car.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><img style="width: 130px; height: 100px" alt="<?php echo $row['car']; ?>" src="image/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['car']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['details']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="selected_car" value="<?php echo $row['car']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then when you submit through to `car.php` the value of `$_POST['selected_car']` will be the whichever car the user selected.

I would strongly recommend adding an ID column to that table and using it in place of the name of the car in the Radio buttons.

I'd also strongly recommend looking at some PHP/MySQL tutorials so you can get to grips with the basics. [This](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php) is quite good for getting started with PHP.

Comment: How would i submit a specific car because this would then eventually display this back to the reader confirming their selection

Comment: I've amended my answer with a simple solution

Comment: That works a treat except it does not display the selected car when submitted. It does not display any errors. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: The most basic way of checking it works is in `car.php` add the line `<?php echo "Selected Car: ".$_POST['selected_car']; ?>`

Comment: I have stored an image in my database. Would you know how i can retrieve this in my page?

Comment: Add a column to your database called `img` add the file names to the corresponding records (e.g. `astra.jpg`). Then edit your select statement to read: `$query = "SELECT car, details, price, img FROM Car";`. Then the code I've supplied you with should take care of the rest, all you've got to do is make sure the image files are in the `images` folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    $_SESSION['car'] = $row['car'];
                    $_SESSION['details'] = $row['details'];
                    $_SESSION['price'] = $row['price'];
                }
```

every new row overwrites the old one.

you could create the html in your while loop, like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<form method="post" action="car.php">
     Car: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['car']; ?>" readonly><br>
     Details: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['details']; ?>" readonly><br>
     Price: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" readonly><br>
     <img style="width: 130px; height: 100px" img alt="car"src="image/astra.jpg" /&gt;' />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> // now you makes a form for each car
<?php
}
```

Comment: This code works but it is displaying several copies of the form. Any idea why?

Comment: yes, because you create a multiple forms. in the while loop i create a form: `<form method="post" action="car.php">` and `</form>`. so for every car a form is created.